# Como distribuir um projeto em C# que usa "LocalDB" para um "outro computador"?

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um projeto da Faculdade em C# para terminar. A aplicação funciona e todas as funcionalidades foram implementadas.

Estou usando LocalDB v12 do Visual Studio 2015 em conjunto com Entity Framework.

O professor prometeu pontos extras para quem conseguir fazer *Publish* da aplicação e ela rodar em **outro computador** que não seja o que foi utilizado pra desenvolver.

Eu consegui usar o publish do Visual Studio 2015, porém, quando tento rodar em outro computador, ele dá um erro de banco de dados. Erro de Conexão com o banco de dados.

Como faço pra dar publish no projeto com o banco de dados junto?

Comment: Que erro ocorre?

Comment: Cannot open database "TesteDB" requested by login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'usuario\xxx",

Comment: Por favor, publique as `<ConnectionStrings>` do seu **web.config**.

Comment: Eu não faria isso. Podem ter informações de autenticação no seu computador. Se for uma máquina numa rede acessível por fora...

Comment: O que você pode fazer, é não associar uma conta do Windows ao LocalDB. Utilize autenticação SQL (sem segurança integrada, e você precisa criar as estruturas de usuário e senha no banco). Assim você deixa sua aplicação desassociada de uma máquina ou rede específica.

Comment: Depois de uma Longa e exaustiva busca, finalmente encontrei a resposta.... no youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zx6w3BDD6Sg Me ajudou pacas esse video. Quem estiver com a mesma dúvida, ele realmente resolve. Consegui instalar em 2 computadores que nem ferramentas de desenvolvimento tinham.